# Fixed - can't log in or change admin password

Tags: magento2, password

Tried to log into magento 2 and received a message saying "it's time to change your password".

filled in all the info and chose a new password. Clikcked Save and got this error message:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Account\Save\Interceptor does not exist
```

I have read posts on here on how to change password with a forgot password link but it doesn't give us any option other than to set a new password and then we get this error message.
can anyone offer any advice please?

Update - our hosting company was really helpful and solved this for us.  It was set to force password reset.  They disabled this and it allowed us to get access and change password.

thank you for the help!

Comment: Please check if the interceptors have been generated properly. If not, then run bin/magento setup:di:compile in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not an issue with change passwords, it may be an issue with permission or with code.

1. If it is related to the permission issue then I would suggest run below code to give permission for var/ pub/ and generated folder

> chmod 777 -R var/ pub/ generated/

2. If it is related to code, then try to disable third-party extensions and still you are getting this issue and then run below command to update your vendor code>

> composer update

3. another suggestion, if you want to disable the admin password to be a forceful feature then you can run the below command to disable this feature.

> php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_lifetime 0
> php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_is_forced 0
> php bin/magento c:f

Please let me know if you need any other help

Comment: Thank you so much.  Unfortunately the one person here with tech knowledge is finished for the holidays :(                  Do you think this is something that is an issue for the  developer we used to migrate us to M2?  I am not sure if your reply suggests he didn't set up our correct permissions ?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Did you try with my other #2 and #2 suggestions?